# Sending string from wpf application to an asp.net website in secure way

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to send a string to a asp.net website and get a result string from the website.
Found this code to send string
How could I get this string on an asp.net website.

```
string dataToSend = "data=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ABCDEFGH12345678");
var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSend);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.babels.ir");
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
req.Method = "POST";

using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
}

// -- execute request and get response
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    Console.WriteLine("Activation code received");
```

Comment: You may use Web API for this.

Comment: You must use a Service(Webservice,Wcfservice,webApi) and call it from your wpf application

Comment: Which approach is better for secure sending and receiving a string

Comment: I think WebApi is better solution...wcf is a few hard to implement... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38691/difference-between-web-api-and-web-service